# Query (8, 5) Parser: The syntax for 'SELECT' is incorrect

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following MDX code and getting the above error on it. I have found a few articles but so confused about how to alter it:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Calculated Member]
 AS SELECT
NON EMPTY
{
 [Measures].[Unit Count]
} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Testing], 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Can someone re write that to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a calculated measure in cube structure tab where you can right click -> New Measure and select the table -> column name and aggregation (count and distinct count within it).

Then you can open AS in SSMS and write query and specify your where clause

`select [Measures].[Order Key Distinct Count] on columns
from testing
WHERE ( [Dim].[Hierarchy].&[Value] )`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Calculated Member]
AS 
[Measures].[Unit Count]
,VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

The definition for calculated member doesn't allow for `SELECT`, `ON` or `NON EMPTY`. Those are meant to be used during data retrieval. 
So, once your member is ready, you can probably use it like this:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Calculated Member] ON 0,
NON EMPTY SomeDim.SomeAttribute.MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Testing]
```

Comment: So i put this code in the script command after i made the calc member, `SELECT NON EMPTY [Measures].[Calculated Member] ON 0
FROM [Testing]; ` but when i deploy it says `Error 2 Invalid query syntax. A valid MDX or DAX query was expected.`

Comment: You misunderstood me. The query that goes in your script is what you see at top of my answer. The query that you should write on your SSMS/reporting tool is what you see at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Ahh that worked, even though i got the wrong value. I was after the count of rows but it summed it all up instead (please do tell me if you know the count expression for this). Thanks anyway

Comment: Count works on a set of members. It's syntax can be found here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144823.aspx and here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146026.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Had another idea gonna try that. I could just make a new measure in cube structure and call that in the query with my where clause (which is what i was working to) thank you for the help :)